# Java runtime exec command ignores quotes

Tags: java

I have a problem. In my code I use the following lines:

```
String runProjectCommand= "java -jar /var/script/projects/project1/target/project1-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar 1 \"" + simulatorRun.getStartDateTime().format(formatter) + "\"";
System.out.println(runProjectCommand);
Process runSimulatorProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(runProjectCommand);
```

The value of `runProjectCommand` is:

```
java -jar /var/script/projects/project1/target/project1-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar 1 "2018-01-01 00:00:00"
```

Then in the project1 code I start off with the following code:

```
if (args != null) {
    for (String string : args) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
    if (args.length == 2) {
        agentId = Integer.parseInt(args[0].substring(args[0].indexOf("=") + 1));
        startDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(args[1].substring(args[1].indexOf("=") + 1), formatter);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Not enough startup arguments given:");
        System.out.println("\t1. AgentId");
        System.out.println("\t2. StartDateTime");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

But the output of this jar file is:

```
1
"2018-01-01
00:00:00"
Not enough startup arguments given:
    1. AgentId
    2. StartDateTime
```

As you can see there are 3 startup parameters instead of 2. This is because of the `"2018-01-01 00:00:00"`, that gets split at the space, while I added double quotes to it. Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ProcessBuilder` instead:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = ProcessBuilder.command(
    "java",
    "-jar",
    "/var/script/projects/project1/target/project1-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar",
    "1",
    simulatorRun.getStartDateTime().format(formatter));
Process runSimulatorProcess = pb.start();
```

Note that this doesn't use quotes. Quotes are a thing your shell deals with; you're not invoking this in a shell.